# Load Knockout observableArray not working

Tags: jquery, json, asp.net-mvc-4, knockout.js

Trying to load an observableArray with json from server like this:

```
function InsightViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.Name = ko.observable("");

    var insightData = {
        Name: self.Name
    };

    self.insightData = ko.observable();
    self.Insights = ko.observableArray([]);

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: '@Url.Action("GetIndexData", "Admin")',
        contentType: "application/json",
        dataType: "json",
        data:{},
        success: function (data) {
            self.Insights(data);
            alert(JSON.stringify(data) + "Array length " + self.Insights.length);
        },
        error: function (error) {
            alert(error.status + " " + error.statusText);
        }
    });
};

var viewModel = new InsightViewModel();
ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
alert(viewModel.Insights.length);
```

I can alert out the json from the server, and it is valid. But the array is empty.

I tried this, with no luck:

```
$(data).each(function (element) {
   self.Insights.push(element);
});
```

Not that experienced with knockout. Any thoughts?

Comment: `alert(viewModel.Insights.length);` is probably running before your `$.ajax.sucess` callback invoked. What if you try `ko.dataFor(document.body).Insights().length`?

Comment: You are incorrectly get length `Insights` array, it should be `self.Insights().length` (with brackets).

Comment: You're right Alexander, my bad...

Comment: You don't need to set `contentType` and `dataType` in the Ajax call. The server does that by sending the right response header and jQuery will pick it up automatically. Just leave it off.

Comment: @Alexander Could you create an answer, so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are incorrectly get length `Insights` observableArray, it should be like this:

```
self.Insights().length // with brackets
```

Another problem, as described @haim770 is calling `alert` after `ko.applyBindings(viewModel)`. There is a big chance, that ajax request is not completed yet.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why the array is empty because by default ajax is asyncronous. the work around is to add async: false in your ajax call, but that is not the best practic. Instead of adding async : false use .done...

```
function InsightViewModel() {
     var self = this;
     self.Name = ko.observable("");

    var insightData = {
        Name: self.Name
    };

    self.insightData = ko.observable();
    self.Insights = ko.observableArray([]);

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: '@Url.Action("GetIndexData", "Admin")',
        contentType: "application/json",
        dataType: "json"            
    })
    .done(function(data)
    {
        self.Insights(data);
    });
 };

var viewModel = new InsightViewModel();
ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
alert(viewModel.Insights.length());
```

Hope this work...